# SwiftUI – Multi column TableView in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have been experimenting a bit with SwiftUI and can’t seem to find any information at all about how to use SwiftUI to create a multi column `TableView` as in `NSTableView`. All the examples I have managed to find show a single column of data.

The documentation at Apple even specifies that the SwiftUI `List` structure is for single column display of rows of data. This is a pretty fundamental data structure for apps on MacOS yet there seems to be zero mention of it anywhere!

Can someone shed some light on this? I presume it just isn’t ready yet but still.

Comment: What about column swapping and resizing, headers, row sorting by clicking on sort button in headers etc. MacOS tableviews are way more complicated than just a simple list.

Comment: I think at the moment it's still necessary to use `NSViewRepresentable`. Do you have any new informations?

Comment: No, no new information. And you are right about the lack of examples for MacOS - nearly non existent.

Comment: Did you find out how to use a `NSTableView` in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 13):

## Update for macOS 12+ (Monterey)

In macOS Monterey, `NSTableView` can now be wrapped with `Table`. In addition, `Table` can support `TableColumn`s with key paths and trailing closures.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var characters = StoryCharacter.previewData

  var body: some View {
    Table(characters) {
      TableColumn("") { CharacterIcon($0) }
        .width(20)
      TableColumn("Villain") { Text($0.isVillain ? "Villain" : "Hero") }
        .width(40)
      TableColumn("Name", value: \.name)
      TableColumn("Powers", value: \.powers)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct but keep in mind there is as of Monterey no way to have editable cells.

Answer (score 4):

### SwiftUI Table in Xcode 14.0+

SwiftUI `Table` is a container that presents rows of data arranged in one or more columns, optionally providing the ability to select its members and sort its members in ascending or descending order. Each `TableColumn` struct displays a view for each row in a table.

[image]

Here's a code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var item: String
    var qty: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
     
    @State var sorting = [KeyPathComparator(\Item.qty)]
    @State var selecting: Int?      
    @State var items: [Item] = [1,2,3,4,5].map {
        Item(id: $0, item: "item \($0)", qty: "qty " + String($0))
    }      
    var body: some View {            
        VStack {  
            Table(items, selection: $selecting, sortOrder: $sorting) {
                TableColumn("##", value: \.id) { entity in
                    Text("\(entity.id)").font(.title2)
                }
                TableColumn("What", value: \.item) { entity in
                    Text(entity.item).font(.title2)
                }
                TableColumn("Qty", value: \.qty) { entity in 
                    Text("\(entity.qty)").font(.title2)
                }
            }.frame(width: 900, height: 210)
             .onChange(of: sorting) { items.sort(using: $0) }
             .font(.title)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is now available starting with macOS 12 through [`Table`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/table).

Answer (score 1):

You could create an HStack and then have a divider between two VStacks where you would put your different columns of data. It would look something like this:

```
List {
    HStack {
        VStack {
            //Column 1 Data
        }
    }
    Divider()
    VStack {
        //Column 2 Data
    }
}
```

And then just repeat this for however many columns of data are needed.

Comment: Well yes, but it would look and feel pretty hacked together. No column headers or column swapping, sorting etc.  Better to use a real one for the time being and hope that something better is available after WWDC this year. I was more surprised at the total lack of even a mention of it - pretty well anywhere actually.

Answer (score -1):

For Example:-

```
struct StaffList: View {
   private var data = [Data]()
    var body: some View {
       List {
            HStack() {
                    VStack {
                        //Column 1 Data
                        Text("Name")
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            .font(.headline)
                        Divider()
                        ForEach(data) { person in
                          //  Text(person.name) this is list ...
                        }
                    }
                Divider()
                VStack {
                    //Column 2 Data
                    Text("Creation Date")
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .font(.headline)
                    Divider()
                        ForEach(data) { person in
                          //  Text(person.name) this is list ...
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```